# PHP - Issues with infinite looping

Tags: php

I have no clue what I am doing wrong.  EVERY time it goes through it just keeps looping and pulling all of the cities listed in the same row and placing them with the state, then when it goes to the next state it starts at the correct place, but still keeps going.  I've tried for 4 hours I just can't figure it out.

```
$url = 'http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites';
$output = file_get_contents($url); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //Supress Warnings for HTML5 conversion issue
$doc->loadHTML($output);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false); //Start Showing Errors

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);    

foreach ($xpath->query('//h1') as $e) {
    $country = $e->nodeValue;
    $list = array();
    foreach ($xpath->query('./following-sibling::div[@class="colmask"]', $e) as $li) {

        foreach ($xpath->query('//div/h4', $e) as $div) {
            $state = $div->nodeValue;


            foreach ($xpath->query('./following-sibling::ul/li', $div) as $div2) {                      

                $href =  $div2->getAttribute("href");
                $text = trim(preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $div2->nodeValue));
                echo 'Country: ' . $country . ' State: ' . $state . ' CITY: text['. $text . '] href[' . $href . '] <br/><br/><br/>';


            }


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 4 nested `foreach` loops..wohoo..

Comment: I didn't know how else to do it... The elements are outside of eachother and I needed to grab 2 different "headers" ontop of the loop for cities.

Comment: Have you tried limited sample data to see whether the infinite loop occurs for the sample set? For example, a set that has a set of USA, Alabama, and the cities and just see how that turns out?

Comment: Yea it does the same.  The thing is it STARTS on the next state listing the cities correctly, its just not stopping until it gets all the way down the first [list] of cities.

Comment: no problems on my end. works just fine. if its still slow on your parts then consider refactoring it.

Comment: Ghost, if you try it again Alabama loads all the cities for alabama, but then continues on and lists the Alaska cities next to alabama.  It doesn't just stop at listing just the Alabama cities

Comment: @MattHam doesn't happen on my end, loads until tunisia. here as well http://codepad.viper-7.com/hyNh1O

Comment: if you look at your results it lists Country: US State: Alabama CITY: text[anchorage / mat-su] href[]  which anchorage is actually Alaska (10th one down from top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had someone named DuffyDake answer my question.  Here is the answer..

```
foreach ($xpath->query('./following-sibling::ul[1]/li', $div) as $div2) {                      

                $href =  $div2->getAttribute("href");
                $text = trim(preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $div2->nodeValue));
                echo 'Country: ' . $country . ' State: ' . $state . ' CITY: text['. $text . '] href[' . $href . '] <br/><br/><br/>';


            }
```

The missing piece is the [1] to reference to the first UL found and not anything past that

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid nesting `query` calls as you do it. Use rather the DOMNodeList obtained at each iteration, with the `item` method.

For instance, instead of writing:

```
foreach ($xpath->query('./following-sibling::div[@class="colmask"]', $e) as $li) {
    foreach ($xpath->query('//div/h4', $e) as $div) {
        $state = $div->nodeValue;
```

Write:

```
$result = $xpath->query('./following-sibling::div[@class="colmask"]', $e);
$state = $result->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

If you need to navigate from DOMNode `$state`, use `$state->parentNode`, `$state->nextSibling`, and/or `$state->previousSibling`

Comment: I did this and it still shows the $state name correctly, but how do I pull the cities out of the next node?

Comment: I have tried looking for a while but how do i return, or go through the results of the nextSibling?